# Sum of Dates between, T-SQL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp

I'm trying to check if one of the join_date or date_of_change (date fields) are within the range and count them but I get an error:

> sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from int to
>   TIMESTAMP is unsupported.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (join_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) OR (date_of_change BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
```

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Original Code:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT mtype, CASE WHEN (join_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, 
GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) OR (date_of_change BETWEEN 
DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END AS Total FROM T0 GROUP BY mype, join_date,date_of_change
```

Comment: What is the rest of the statement?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT mtype, CASE WHEN (join_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) OR (date_of_change BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Total
FROM T0
GROUP BY mype, join_date,date_of_change

Comment: That's an error originating from however you execute that (i.e. jdbc) or other SQL in the batch - the statement itself would not cause that error if executed correctly - i.e. there is no TIMESTAMP involvement

Comment: I just wanted to group them by mtype. but When I do that I get an error saying to add join_date and date_of_change to aggregate function so I had to put them there but obviously it's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alex K has said there could be another statement in the batch causing the problem as there doesn't seem to be any TimeStamp involved in this query.

Answering your last comment about the GROUP BY, you can simplify the query the following way:

```
SELECT 
    mtype, COUNT(1) as Total
FROM 
    T0 
WHERE 
    (join_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) 
    OR (date_of_change BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) 
GROUP BY 
    mype
```

But I am afraid that if the error is in a different statement.

Comment: thank you for that but as I add more rows to this table I cant just use where

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the query again and it worked, must be a typo somewhere